# Is there a dsl for AWS EC2?

Tags: dsl, cloud-hosting

I am looking at using Amazon cloud services (EC2, S3 etc) for hosting. I've been looking at the JSON metadata that can be specified to configure various instances and the complexity has me concerned. Is there a dsl that will generate valid JSON metadata and more importantly validate the entries?

Comment: There are Grails plugins for AWS and S3 that might be relevant http://grails.org/plugin/aws http://grails.org/plugin/amazon-s3

Comment: I've used that amazon-s3 plugin, and it works great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, I drew a blank after searching for this recently. I'm using Amazon Web Services CloudFormation (is that the JSON metadata you're talking about?).

There are a couple of issues with CloudFormation JSON files:

1. I'm at well over 1,500 lines and it's impossible to read,
2. You can't express everything the API gives you, notably in the area of Virtual Private Clouds,
3. There are lots of bugs that are taking a long time to fix, Elastic Load Balancers losing HTTPS information, for example.

So I've been using straight-up API calls in Scala using the Java API. It's actually really nice.

The Java API has a flavor of "setters" starting with `with` that return `this` so they can be chained. In Scala, you can use these to act like a poor-man's DSL. So you can do things like

```
val updateRequest = new UpdateAutoScalingGroupRequest()
                    .withAutoScalingGroupName(group.getAutoScalingGroupName)
                    .withAvailabilityZones(subnetAZsOfOurVPC)
                    .withVPCZoneIdentifier(subnetNamesOfOurVPC)

as.updateAutoScalingGroup(updateRequest)
```

Other things are easy to do in Scala with the Java API. For example, group all your Subnets by VPC in a Map, simply do

```
val subnetsByVPC = ec2.describeSubnets(new DescribeSubnetsRequest).getSubnets.groupBy(_.getVpcId)
```

Comment: I've ended up doing essentially this, I've built some groovy scripts using the Java AWS API. I've added some meta-programming to groovy-ise the API and add some missing options. Works pretty good.

Comment: The demands of my day job are preventing me from writing a full-blown Scala DSL for the Amazon Web Services Java API. It would be awesome. And, frankly, a lot better than CloudFormation, which doesn't appear to be getting a lot of attention at Amazon for some reason. It's quite buggy.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is still looking for the AWS CloudFormation DSL - we've been using the [Ruby DSL for CloudFormation](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/cloudformation-ruby-dsl):

https://github.com/bazaarvoice/cloudformation-ruby-dsl

- This neat project provides a tool to convert your existing CloudFormation template(s) to the Ruby DSL
- It will generate valid JSON output
- Validating Ruby template entries is similar to validating a regular CloudFormation template (see *cfn-validate-template*)
- Your template becomes Ruby code, so it's easy to have reusable modules (DRY)
- You can define local variables
- You can have comments in your DSL template
- Greatly improved readability
- Greatly reduced DSL template size

The CloudFormation request template body [size limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cloudformation-limits.html) are annoying - we have to upload our large CloudFormation templates to S3, then create/update stacks using their S3 URLs.

Answer (score 0):

There is now, though I haven't used it yet: [Coffin](http://chrisfjones.github.com/coffin/) a CoffeeScript DSL for CloudFormation.

If you're not talking about CloudFormation, but instead more general API talking, then the nicest interface I've found is [AWS' own aws-sdk ruby gem](https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-ruby).  Unlike the other SDKs that they publish which are quite nicely-done-but-crude make-client/make-request/get-response/look-at-result affairs, the [ruby SDK wraps a nicer domain-model over the top, so you interact via collections at a higher abstract level](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/frames.html%5d).

It also has quite-nice performance features in that you can cache responses to save on round-trips, if you know you don't need fresh responses.

Answer (score 0):

I have CloudFormation templates upwards of 3000 lines.  I have found that putting comments in the JSON helps tremendously!!  You just have to strip it out before using it.  There is a validator that would validate the template and strip out the comments:  http://cloudformation-validation.com/

Comment: You can add "Metadata" sections almost anywhere in CloudFormation templates, and they may contain arbitrary data, so I use those for comments. This has the benefit that the comments remain in the template for anyone who comes across the template but doesn't know where the source is.

Answer (score 0):

No, as of Feb 2022, AWS still does not provide any domain-specific language for infrastructure as code.  They have nothing similar to [Azure's Bicep](https://github.com/Azure/bicep) or [Terraform's HCL](https://www.terraform.io/language/syntax/configuration).

This really surprises me, as I generally think of AWS as being more expensive, but ahead of the curve, compared to other major competitors (Azure and GCP).

However, Cloud Formation now allows both JSON and YAML formats.  Slight improvement??  IMHO, not really when you have an entire repo that represents your entire cloud stack.  If you're using AWS, use Terraform to manage IaC.